# file upload html5 asp.net web method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to upload the file to the server using html5 input control with type="file".
The client side javascript code is as below.

```
var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

        xhr.open("POST", "Default.aspx", true);
        xhr.send(fd);
```

here in

```
xhr.open("POST", "Default.aspx/Test", true);
```

if i give a **web method("Test")**, the control is not hitting the server where as if I remove the webmethod and give plain

```
xhr.open("POST", "Default.aspx", true);
```

the control is hitting the page_load method.

What am I missing so that the web method is not getting hit.

Regards,
Rakesh

Comment: Can you provide the Default.aspx.cs usefull code?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing so that the web method is not getting hit.

First you must have a static method on your Default.aspx.cs page

```
public static void Test()
```

Decorated with WebMethod attribute.

```
using System.Web.services;

[WebMethod]
public static void Test()
```

In this way the webmethod get hit but I'm not sure what kind of parameter the method should have or if you can access the posted file by using **HttpContext.Current.Request.Files**

You can look a this example :

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/374136/Call-Page-Method-From-Jquery-Ajax-Call

Comment: Sorry, I dint give you complete information in my initial post. I have Test method in the code behind file. It looks like this `[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void Test()
    { // DO something here}`

Comment: Make the Method static on web page